# How to change a String as I am scanning text Java

Tags: java, maze, scanning

I am trying to replace a "." with an "X". This is eventually for a text based maze that the computer will figure out. I just want to get the first one changed, and hopefully I can figure the rest out from there. This is what I have so far.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(maze2);

public void traverseMaze(int row, int col, int handLocationX, int handLocationY) {

    for(int rowCount = 0; rowCount <=11 ; rowCount ++){
        row = rowCount;

        for(int colCount = 0; colCount <= 11; colCount++){
            col = colCount;

            if(row ==2 && col ==0){
                System.out.println(col);
                System.out.println(row);
                sc.next().replace(".", "X"); //stuck here HELP! :)
            }
        }
        System.out.println(maze2);
    }
```

Comment: what is sc? please explain what have you done and is there an error at all.

Comment: sorry about that, sc is the scanner. No errors.

Comment: In case sc.next() returns a String, please remind that String.replace() doesn't modify the string itself but rather returns a new string in which the occurence has been replaced.

Comment: I will give it a shot thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `String` is immutable, so

```
sc.next().replace(".", "X"); //stuck here HELP! :)
```

should be something like this

```
String orgStr = sc.next();
String newStr = orgStr.replace(".", "X");
```